# Candidates for non-sofic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

What are the "simplest" examples of countable groups that are not known to be sofic?

Comment: I think Thompson's groups are not known to be sofic. See Pestov's survey: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.cmu.edu%2F~eschimme%2FAppalachian%2FPestovNotes.pdf&ei=uVIAU-LpNZTloATrmILwCg&usg=AFQjCNF_6V5KHmtEdlvIl8IRGJubIyRhUA&sig2=BrH72bY4jy3iBbv21864EA&bvm=bv.61535280,d.cGU

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest candidate I know of is Higman's group

$\langle a,b,c,d\mid a^b=a^2, b^c=b^2, c^d=c^2, d^a=d^2\rangle$

(where, as usual, $a^b$ means $b^{-1}ab$).  Terry Tao wrote a nice blog post about it [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/finite-subsets-of-groups-with-no-finite-models/).

Residually finite and amenable groups are both known to be sofic. As Tao explains, Higman's group has no finite quotients (hence is 'highly non-residually finite') and a non-abelian free subgroup (hence is certainly non-amenable).

Comment: Thank you very much! Are there any non-residually finite non-amenable groups that are known to be sofic?

Comment: Soficity is preserved under direct products, so just take a direct product of non-amenable and non residually finite sofic groups, such as a free group and a Baumslag-Solitar group like $\langle x,y \mid y^{-1}x^2y=x^3 \rangle$.

Comment: A more recent reference appears here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02135